# Node JS upload file streams over HTTP

Tags: node.js, request, fetch, axios

I'm switching one of my projects from `request` over to something a bit more light-weight (such as got, axios, or fetch). Everything is going smoothly, however, I'm having an issue when attempting to upload a file stream (`PUT` and `POST`). It works fine with the request package, but any of the other three return a 500 from the server.

I know that a 500 generally means an issue on the server's end, but it is consistent only with the HTTP packages that I'm testing out. When I revert my code to use `request`, it works fine.

Here is my current Request code:

```
Request.put(`http://endpoint.com`, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${account.token.access_token}`
  },
  formData: {
    content: fs.createReadStream(localPath)
  }
}, (err, response, body) => {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }

  return callback(null, body);
});
```

And here is one of the attempts using another package (in this case, got):

```
got.put(`http://endpoint.com`, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${account.token.access_token}`,
  },
  body: {
    content: fs.createReadStream(localPath)
  }
})
  .then(response => {
    return callback(null, response.body);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return callback(err);
  });
```

Per the got documentation, I've also tried using the `form-data` package in conjunction with it according to its example and I still get the same issue.

The only difference between these 2 I can gather is with `got` I do have to manually specify the `Content-Type` header otherwise the endpoint does give me a proper error on that. Otherwise, I'm not sure how the 2 packages are constructing the body with the stream, but as I said, `fetch` and `axios` are also producing the exact same error as `got`.

If you want any of the snippets using `fetch` or `axios` I'd be happy to post them as well.

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but according to the got documentation you need to pass a FormData as the body of the object - https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#form-data

Comment: I did try this as well. Using the `form-data` package, I called `append` with 'content' and the stream info but I still get the same issue. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was a headers issue. If I use the headers directly from `FormData` (i.e., `headers: form.getHeaders()`) and just add in my additional headers afterwards (`Authorization`), then this ends up working just fine.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but I too am missing the simple [pipe support from the request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming)

```
const request = require('request');

request
  .get("https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg")
  .pipe(request.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload/stream"))


// Or any readable stream
fs.createReadStream('/Users/file/path/localFile.jpeg')
  .pipe(request.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload/stream"))
```

and had to do some experimenting to find similar features from current libraries.

Unfortunately, I haven't worked with "got" but I hope the following 2 examples help someone else that are interested in working with the Native [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)/[https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) libraries or the popular [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) library

---

#### HTTP/HTTPS

Supports piping!

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

console.log("[i] Test pass-through: http/https");

// Note: http/https must match URL protocol
https.get(
  "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg",
  (imageStream) => {
    console.log("    [i] Received stream");

    imageStream.pipe(
      http.request("http://localhost:8000/api/upload/stream/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": imageStream.headers["content-type"],
        },
      })
    );
  }
);

// Or any readable stream
fs.createReadStream('/Users/file/path/localFile.jpeg')
  .pipe(
    http.request("http://localhost:8000/api/upload/stream/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": imageStream.headers["content-type"],
      },
    })
  )
```

#### Axios

Note the usage of `imageStream.data` and that it's being attached to `data` in the Axios config.

```
const axios = require('axios');

(async function selfInvokingFunction() {
  console.log("[i] Test pass-through: axios");

  const imageStream = await axios.get(
    "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg",
    {
      responseType: "stream", // Important to ensure axios provides stream
    }
  );

  console.log("  [i] Received stream");

  const upload = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload/stream/",
    data: imageStream.data,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": imageStream.headers["content-type"],
    },
  });

  console.log("Upload response", upload.data);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for the Axios solution. Response type 'stream' works fine when used as multipart POST

Comment: And thank you for the "HTTP/HTTPS Supports piping!" example - that implementation was the closest to my ```request``` implementation. Been trying to shift away from ```request``` since it was depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For me just works when I added other parameters on FormData.

**before**

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fileStream);
```

**after**

```
const form = new FormData();
form.append('file', fileStream, 'my-whatever-file-name.mp4');
```

So that way I can send stream from my backend to another backend in node, waiting a file in multipart/form-data called 'file'